# XSD from sample XML

Tags: xml, xsd

How do I write an XSD for these sample XML tags?

```
              <Vote> 
                <UBF Name="DATE">2020-04-16</UBF>
                <UBF Name="SEC">22</UBF>
                <UBF Name="BATCHID">ABCD</UBF>
                <UBF Name="EFFECTIVE">2020-04-16</UBF>
                <UBF Name="TRACK">BCDE</UBF>
                <UBF Name="AUTH">EFGH</UBF>
                <UBF Name="COMMAMT">7.1</UBF>
                <UBF Name="SIZE">9.2</UBF>
                <UBF Name="PCT">8.2</UBF>
                <UBF Name="CIF">OT</UBF>
                <UBF Name="SECID">22</UBF>
                <UBF Name="EXPDATE">2020-11-30</UBF>
                <UBF Name="TOTSHAR">3.2</UBF>
            </Vote>
```

Note: All the elements/ attributes are required and in sequence, and the values passed are different for different elements. for e.g., the value in DATE should be passed as a date in yyyy-mm-dd, while the value in BATCHID is char(30), and the value in COMMAMT should be passed as a decimal.

I tried using the online XML to XSD converters, and I came up with the following code. But, it doesn't address the need to pass different types of values for individual elements

```
                      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UBF">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                              <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:extension>
                          </xs:simpleContent>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a code writing for hire web site. You need to show your effort

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I've added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `<UBF />` element, what you want is a union of the simple types **string**, **date**, **int** and **decimal**:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ubfValuesUnion">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:string xs:date xs:int xs:decimal" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

The `<UBF />` element definition becomes:

```
<xs:element name="UBF">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="ubfValuesUnion">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This then allows your XML to be validated with those different values for dates, strings, integer and decimal numbers.

Comment: But. what if I want to specifically limit the passage of each attribute value?
e.g., the value in <UBF Name="DATE"> should be passed as a date in yyyy-mm-dd only, and in no other format

Comment: @ user13357411 You have to use a feature called Type Alternatives for that. That requires XSD v1.1 however, and can make your schema very complex. I would recommend for that type of validation to let the application do that and not put that in the schema. You can read about Type Alternatives in section 5 of https://www.xml.com/articles/2018/05/29/co-occurrence-cta-xsd/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest documentation for the XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) at: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/

Answer (score 0):

> All the elements/ attributes are required and in sequence, and the values passed are different for different elements. for e.g., the value in DATE should be passed as a date in yyyy-mm-dd, while the value in BATCHID is char(30), and the value in COMMAMT should be passed as a decimal.

You will find this part of the XSD specification *very* useful: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/
It lists all the of the built-in simple datatypes, their lexical forms and constraints.

> I tried using the online XML to XSD converters

I don't find those converters very useful, in general. Even a simple schema can allow many different documents. It is very unlikely that a single example document will capture everything that your schema needs to specify.